# Error on creating view of type under another type - ORA-00932 "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying create view for object created under another object.

But it don't work (ORA-00932).

When using object not under another object it works correctly...

Can someone explain me why?

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    ID_Person       NUMBER(7,0)     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    Surname         VARCHAR2(30)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT      Person_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_Person)
    );
/
CREATE TABLE Client (
    ID_Client       NUMBER(7,0)     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1) NOT NULL,
    Email           VARCHAR2(45)    NOT NULL,
    ID_Person       NUMBER(7,0)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT      Client_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID_Client),
    CONSTRAINT      Client_Person_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID_Person)  REFERENCES Person(ID_Person)
    );
/
CREATE TYPE person_objtyp AS OBJECT (
    Surname        VARCHAR2(30)
    ) NOT FINAL;
/
CREATE TYPE client_objtyp UNDER person_objtyp (
    ID_Client       NUMBER(7,0),
    Email           VARCHAR2(45)
    );
/
CREATE VIEW client_objv OF client_objtyp
    WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER (ID_Client)
    AS SELECT k.ID_Client, k.Email, o.Surname
    FROM Client k JOIN Person o ON k.ID_Person = o.ID_Person; -- ERROR ORA-00932
/
DROP TYPE client_objtyp;
/
CREATE TYPE client_objtyp AS OBJECT (
    ID_Client       NUMBER(7,0),
    Email           VARCHAR2(45),
    Surname         VARCHAR2(30)
    );
/
CREATE VIEW client_objv OF client_objtyp
    WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER (ID_Client)
    AS SELECT k.ID_Client, k.Email, o.Surname
    FROM Client k JOIN Person o ON k.ID_Person = o.ID_Person; -- WORK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the first case, there exists a mismatch with the definition of the return type(client_objtyp) and what you already have (three columns). Therefore you need to cast by `client_objtyp` as :

```
CREATE VIEW client_objv OF client_objtyp
    WITH OBJECT IDENTIFIER (ID_Client)
    AS SELECT client_objtyp(k.ID_Client, k.Email, o.Surname)
    FROM Client k JOIN Person o ON k.ID_Person = o.ID_Person
```

But there's no such situation occurs for the second case. Number of columns and their types match with the type `client_objtyp`.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=cfa632b2d1dedd0d1dca2f6f7915edff)</kbd>